# jQuery Mobile changePage not working with data-prefetch

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

jQuery mobile change page event not working in internal pages

```
  $.mobile.changePage('xyz.html');
```

if i use data-prefetch in any url.

Can anyone help me to solve ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly this has nothing to do with data prefetch. If you pretetch another **`HTML`** file with multiple internal pages only first internal page will be loaded, everything else is going to be discarded, including HEAD part of a mentioned **`HTML`** file.

There are two good article talking about this situation, **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/secrets-of-a-good-jquery-mobile-page-architecture/)** and **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/)**, to be transparent it is my personal blog.

In a few words, only first (original) HTML file should have more then one internal page, usually pages most commonly used. Everything else should be in external **`HTML`** files just to prevent large **`DOM`** size.

Comment: I don't have multipage concept... I am using internal pages means no rel="external".

Comment: Then why are you using $.mobile.changePage('xyz.html') if your pages are all part of a single HTML file?

Comment: In my app, I have login page and after login, i want to redirect to some page that's why I have used...

Comment: Is your login page separate html page the rest of your app?

Comment: Then this is your problem. If you read my answer, I told you that only first HTML page (in your case login page) can have more then 1 internal page. All other pages can have only and only 1 internal page. So if your second page has several pages and you use $.mobile.changePage('xyz.html') to change page it will load first data-role="page" from your second HTML and everything else is going to be discarded.

Comment: data-prefetch is also creating flickering issue